# How long should I wait before upgrading to Ubuntu 15?

Tags: upgrade

I am new to this 'fast-update process' and wondering what the suggested  time would be to wait before switching from (let's say) 14.04 to 15.04?

My main concerns are compatibility issues and unavailable software.

Comment: It is a personal choice. You can transfer as soon as 15.04 is released or you can keep using 14.04 till beginning of 2019 and then transfer to 18.04.

Comment: Finally decided to go back to 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

15.04's been out since April, so a lot has been fixed by way of compatibility, performance and bugs. It might be better to stay on 14.04, though, since it's LTS, which means longer support. 16.04 will also be LTS, so if you want an upgrade, that'll be it. It's really up to you.

Comment: Why do you recommend staying on 14?

Comment: Just put it in. I accidentally submitted it.

Comment: Everything that runs on 14 runs on 15 or that is not given?

Comment: It should, but since 15.04 doesn't have support for nearly as long as 14.04, I'd stay on 14 and wait for 16.04, since it's the next LTS release.

Answer (score 0):

15.04 is not an LTS release. You can't directly upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04. And 14.10 is not supported any more.

If you really need 15.04, then it is better to do a fresh install. But it is better to stick with LTS if there is no specific reason to upgrade.

Comment: What happened was Ubuntu suggested an upgrade to 14.10 yesterday and when applied recommended to upgrade to 15.04.

Comment: 14.10 is not supported. Since you started upgrading, then it is a good idea to upgrade now.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon If you've already upgraded to 14.10, you should just go to 15.04 because, like Pilot6 said, 14.10 is no longer supported, while 15.04 will be for a little while longer.